# Deleting tweets with JS console

Tags: javascript, dom, settimeout, console.log

I am trying to delete tweets in the JS console on my Twitter page.
If I do it manually by selecting the button and then doing a click, I can manually run 3 different functions.

```
const delButton=()=>{
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="caret"]')[0].click()
};
const clickDel=()=>{
    document.querySelector("#layers > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-1d2f490.r-105ug2t.r-u8s1d.r-zchlnj.r-ipm5af > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-yfoy6g.r-z2wwpe.r-xnswec.r-1ekmkwe.r-1udh08x.r-u8s1d > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-16y2uox.r-1wbh5a2 > div > span");
};
const confirmDel=()=>{
    document.querySelector("#layers > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div > div > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-1awozwy.r-1kihuf0.r-18u37iz.r-1pi2tsx.r-1777fci.r-1pjcn9w.r-fxte16.r-1xcajam.r-ipm5af.r-9dcw1g > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-1awozwy.r-yfoy6g.r-1867qdf.r-1jgb5lz.r-pm9dpa.r-1ye8kvj.r-1rnoaur.r-d9fdf6.r-1sxzll1.r-13qz1uu > div.css-1dbjc4n.r-18u37iz.r-13qz1uu > div.css-18t94o4.css-1dbjc4n.r-1dgebii.r-42olwf.r-sdzlij.r-1phboty.r-rs99b7.r-16y2uox.r-1w2pmg.r-1vuscfd.r-1dhvaqw.r-1ny4l3l.r-1fneopy.r-o7ynqc.r-6416eg.r-lrvibr > div > span > span").click()
} 

delButton();
clickDel();
confirmDel();
```

I have tried a few different ways, if I run them manually by running each function in the console, it works. However when i try to put them into a function that runs all 3, the second one doesn't click because it isn't ready yet. I tried using a setTimeout before firing them but it still hasn't worked. I also tried using async and await but I think my understanding of the problem is limited.

```
const runEmAll=()=>{
    setTimeout(delButton(), 1000); 
    setTimeout(clickDel(), 1000);
    setTimeout(confirmDel(), 1000);
}
runEmAll();

// or I also tried...
const runDel = async ()=>{
    await delButton();
}
runDel().then(clickDel());
```

Again that didn't work.. The error I get is

```
VM1649:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
```

referring to the clickDel function

Comment: I don't want to be _that_ guy, but is it possible for you to use something like [puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer)?

Comment: I could use puppeteer or selenium but I just wanted something quick and dirty!

Comment: Gotcha, one thing that stands out is you're calling the function in your setTimeouts, which will execute them immediately. Change to `setTimeout(delButton, 1000)` etc.

Comment: Thanks Phix, tried that but it still didn't work.  
It needs to run delButton, wait a second so that the menu appears, and then hit the clickDel()

Comment: Tried nesting them too

`nestedTimeouts=()=>{
    setTimeout(delButton,1000, setTimeout(clickDel,1000));
}`

Comment: Okay that works `()=>{
    setTimeout(delButton, 1000); 
    setTimeout(clickDel, 1000);
    setTimeout(confirmDel, 1000);
}`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

. open Chrome or whatever browser.

(click order and buttons may different vary if browser is not
Chrome).

. open twitter.

. click profile or click tweets and replies

. press F12 (developer options)

. click Console Tab

. paste this codes (twitter language must be English)

```
var delTweets = function () {
var tweetsRemaining = 
document.querySelectorAll('[role="heading"]+div')[1].textContent;
console.log('Remaining: ', tweetsRemaining);
window.scrollBy(0, 10000);
document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="More"]').forEach(function 
(v, i, a) {
    v.click();
    document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(function (v2, i2, a2) {
        if (v2.textContent === 'Delete') {
            v2.click();
            document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="confirmationSheetConfirm"]').forEach(function (v3, i3, a3) {
                v3.click();
            });
        }
        else {
            document.body.click();
        }
    });
});
setTimeout(delTweets, 4000); //less than 4000 might be rate limited or account suspended. increase timeout if any suspend or rate limit happens
}
delTweets();
```

Comment: Works like a charm. And likes?

Comment: Gracias, still works at time of posting.

Comment: you need to refresh page, when you are done

Answer (score 9):

I was using Uzay's solution but it stopped working. Here is my solution, which also removes retweets.

To use it, go to your Twitter timeline then go to "tweets" tab to delete all tweets, OR go to "replies" tab to delete replies.

Paste the following code into the browser JavaScript console.

Make sure you set your twitter handle in the code before pasting it!

**Script 1: - delete all tweets**

```
// TO DELETE TWEETS MUST BE RUN FROM https://twitter.com/{yourTwitterHandle}
// TO DELETE REPLIES MUST BE RUN FROM https://twitter.com/{yourTwitterHandle}/with_replies

// IMPORTANT IMPORTANT IMPORTANT - SET YOUR TWITTER HANDLE IN THE NEXT LINE!
// IMPORTANT IMPORTANT IMPORTANT - SET YOUR TWITTER HANDLE IN THE NEXT LINE!
const yourTwitterHandle = "@yourhandle";
// one every 10 seconds to avoid Twitter noticing
const waitTimeSeconds = 10
const sleep = async (seconds) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000));
const main = async () => {
    while (true) {
        await walkTweets();
        await sleep(waitTimeSeconds)
    }
}
const walkTweets = async () => {
    let articles = document.getElementsByTagName('article');
    for (article of articles) {
        const spanElements = article.querySelectorAll('span');
        for (spanElement of spanElements) {
            // delete if it is a retweet
            if (spanElement.textContent === "You reposted") {
                article.scrollIntoView();
                try {
                    const retweetElement = article.querySelector('[data-testid="unretweet"]');
                    if (retweetElement) {
                        retweetElement.click();
                        document.querySelector('[data-testid="unretweetConfirm"]').click();
                    }
                } catch (e) {}
                return
            }

            if (spanElement.textContent === yourTwitterHandle) {
                // in this case it might be a tweet or a reply
                article.scrollIntoView();
                try {
                    // try to delete a reply
                    const tweetReplyElement = article.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="More"]')[1];
                    if (tweetReplyElement) {
                        tweetReplyElement.click()
                        Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('*')).find(el => el.textContent.trim() === 'Delete').click()
                        document.querySelector('[data-testid="confirmationSheetConfirm"]').click();
                        return
                    }
                } catch (e) {}

                try {
                    // try to delete a tweet
                    const tweetElement = article.querySelector('[aria-label="More"]');
                    if (tweetElement) {
                        article.scrollIntoView();
                        tweetElement.click()
                        Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('*')).find(el => el.textContent.trim() === 'Delete').click()
                        document.querySelector('[data-testid="confirmationSheetConfirm"]').click();
                        return
                    }
                } catch (e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
main()
```

**Script 2: - delete all likes**

```
// MUST BE RUN FROM https://twitter.com/{yourTwitterHandle}/likes
// one every 10 seconds to avoid Twitter noticing

const waitTimeSeconds = 2;
const maxRetries = 3;
const sleep = async (seconds) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000));
const unlikeAllTweets = async () => {
    let counter = 0;
    let retryCount = 0;
    while (true) {
        try {
            await sleep(waitTimeSeconds);
            const element = document.querySelector('[data-testid="unlike"]');
            if (element === null) {
                if (retryCount >= maxRetries) {
                    console.log('element was null, no more likes found after retries, finished');
                    return;
                }
                console.log(`element was null, retrying... (${retryCount + 1}/${maxRetries})`);
                retryCount++;
                continue;
            }
            element.scrollIntoView();
            element.click();
            counter++;
            retryCount = 0;  
            console.log(`Unliked a tweet. Total so far: ${counter}`);
            await sleep(0.5);
            // Remove the element's parent from the DOM to avoid it clagging up
            if (element.parentElement) {
                element.parentElement.remove();
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('An error occurred:', error);
        }
    }
};

unlikeAllTweets();
```

Comment: Works fine. But you might need to adjust "You Retweeted", [aria-label="More"], 'Delete' strings to your language.

Comment: After switching the interface language to English, it worked fine. I only edited the code to run every second. This was very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: There's apparently too many pending edits to suggest an edit. But "You retweeted" has now become "You reposted"

Comment: I was a frequent retweeter so the accepted answer stalled out for me as Twitter’s UX wasn’t loading any more original posts to delete after some time. This script work better for me as a result, but it is a fair bit slower than the accepted answer’s script because of the 10 second delay. Your mileage may vary depending on your use case.

Comment: @JeffPeterson I set it to 2 seconds and it seems to work fine.  Choose whatever value you like.

Comment: @DukeDougal yep, I did similar, setting it to 1 second. Using that short of an iteration will cause Twitter to stop getting new messages to show after processing 100+ messages though, so the 2 second delay may be more ideal to avoid Twitter throttling fetching new messages to delete.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Mazen Alhrazi answer (thanks!), tested 21st Dec 2022, this is working:

```js
    (async () => {
      function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
      }
    
      let found;
    
      while (found = document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="caret"]').length) {
    
        // get first tweet
        let tweet = document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="tweet"]')[0];
    
        // if it is a retweet, undo it
        if (tweet.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="unretweet"]').length) {
          tweet.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="unretweet"]')[0].click()
          await sleep(1000)
          document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="unretweetConfirm"]')[0].click()
          await sleep(1000)      
        }
        // is a tweet
        else {
          if (new Date(document.querySelectorAll('[datetime]')[0].getAttribute('datetime')) < new Date('2018')) {
            console.log('Limit date reach')
            break;
          }
    
          tweet.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="caret"]')[0].click()
          await sleep(1000)
          document.querySelectorAll('[role="menuitem"]')[0].click()
          await sleep(1000)
          document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="confirmationSheetConfirm"]')[0].click()
        }
      }
    
      if (!found)
        console.log('No more tweets found');
    
    })();
```

My main problem was retweets are in the middle of your own tweets, so you have to delete both: unretweeting and deleting depending of the type.

I added a filter so you do not delete tweets older than a `Date` (2018 in the example). Edit or remove that `if` if not needed.

It's not perfect, have some problems with some conversations/replies, but it worked for me. Maybe somebody else will fix that cases :)

Comment: is this full or partial?

Answer (score 1):

Following Phix' advice I got it working,

```
()=>{
    setTimeout(delButton, 1000); 
    setTimeout(clickDel, 1000);
    setTimeout(confirmDel, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

login > on your profile > Tweets tab > execute

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="caret"]')[0].click()
await sleep(1000)
document.querySelectorAll('[role="menuitem"]')[0].click()
await sleep(1000)
document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="confirmationSheetConfirm"]')[0].click()
```

Comment: THis is not working, can you please update it

Comment: it works well, https://imgur.com/a/wEYNqFO

Comment: please use codes that I've just posted

Answer (score 1):

```js
var delRetweets = function () {
  var tweetsRemaining = document.querySelectorAll('[role="heading"]+div')[1]
    .textContent;
  window.scrollBy(0, 10000);

  document
    .querySelectorAll('[style="color: rgb(0, 186, 124);"]')
    .forEach(function (v) {
      v.click();
      document.querySelectorAll("span").forEach(function (v2, i2, a2) {
        if (v2.textContent === "Undo repost") {
          v2.click();
        } else {
          document.body.click();
        }
      });
    });

  setTimeout(delRetweets, 4000); //less than 4000 might be rate limited or account suspended. increase timeout if any suspend or rate limit happens
};
delRetweets();

var likeTweets = function () {
  var tweets = document.querySelectorAll('[style="color: rgb(249, 24, 128);"]');
  var index = 0;
  var clickCount = 0;

  var clickNextTweet = function () {
    if (index < tweets.length && clickCount < 999) {
      tweets[index].click();
      index++;
      clickCount++;

      if (clickCount % 50 === 0) {
        // Check if 50 clicks limit reached, wait for 15 minutes before continuing
        setTimeout(clickNextTweet, 900000); // Timeout for 15 minutes (900000 milliseconds)
      } else {
        setTimeout(clickNextTweet, 9000); // Timeout between each click action (adjust as needed)
      }
    } else {
      window.scrollBy(0, 10000);

      if (clickCount >= 999) {
        console.log("Maximum click limit reached. Stopping the process.");
      } else {
        setTimeout(likeTweets, 9000); // Timeout before scrolling and starting the process again (adjust as needed)
      }
    }
  };

  clickNextTweet();
};

likeTweets();
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Adam Boyle's answer, if you want to delete only 50 retweets in one go:

```
var counter = 0;
var delRetweets = function () {
  if (counter >= 50) {
    return;
  }
  
  window.scrollBy(0, 10000);

  document
    .querySelectorAll('[style="color: rgb(0, 186, 124);"]')
    .forEach(function (v) {
      if (counter >= 50) {
        return;
      }
      v.click();
      document.querySelectorAll("span").forEach(function (v2) {
        if (v2.textContent === "Undo Retweet") {
          v2.click();
          counter++;
          console.log(`Retweet delete triggered. Total retweets deleted: ${counter}`); // log the count here
        } else {
          document.body.click();
        }
      });
    });

  setTimeout(delRetweets, 4000);
};
delRetweets();
```